# Mutiple Google ads come dynamically based on condition

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, google-apps

I'm implementing my project in Yii and I'm calling Google ads. It is displaying but it should be show based on a condition.

I'm calling data dynamically from database and I'm calling image with content. 10 category recipes will be displayed after that one ads should be display, but there is displaying once only after that ads are displaying blank.

I wrote my code here please suggest me how can I fix this code. I would like every ten categories that one Google ad will be displayed.

```
<?php $counter=0;  $count123=0; ($posts as $receipe):?>    <div class="post">
<?php $counter=$counter+1;
          if($count123<4 && $counter==9)
          { ?>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-11 wrdLatest" id="imgcontent_rand_recipe">
               <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

            <ins class="adsbygoogle" id="kraftmonsterresponsive"
                style="display:block"
                data-ad-client="xxxxxxxxxxx"
                data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
               <script>
           (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
         </script> 
         <?php 
           $counter=1;   
          $count123=$count123+1; ?> </div>
          <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below. Key points:

- I've used the [Modulus Operator](https://www.php.net/operators.arithmetic) - `%` to work out when you're on each 10th item.
- Assuming your `$posts` array is 0 indexed and consecutive, I've stripped out all your `$counter` vars - you only need the `$k` in the foreach loop
- You had a missing closing `</div>` tag which I added in

Hope this is helpful:

```
// $k is 0 indexed
foreach($posts as $k => $receipe)
{
?>
<div class="post">
<?php 

    // Print your Post or recipe info here
    print_r($receipe);
    
    // Now check for each 10th item
    if((($k + 1) % 10) == 0)
    {
?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-11 wrdLatest">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" id="kraftmonsterresponsive" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1823432637478832" data-ad-slot="3981469793" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
</div><!-- .post -->

<?php
}
```